# Have issues regarding how find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, '') works

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I have some trouble understanding how Selenium's find_elements() method works. Almost each time I am trying to use it, it seems to return a list with a single value, namely only the first occurence of that element. Right now I am trying to scrape some betting websites as a small personal project. The endgoal is to build a program that takes the name of a football team as input and finds which betting company offers the best odds. My program succesfully reaches the page where the team's upcoming matches are listed, but then I encounter a problem. Here's my code:

Say this is the webpage I am trying to scrape:

[link to the site i'm trying to scrape](https://superbet.ro/cautare?query=Steaua)

I am noticing that all the matches information is under an element identifiable by the class = 'event-row-container'. There are multiple elements containing this class on the webpage. However:

```
matches = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "event-row-container")

for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

prints only one occurence of the element. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please include a minimal, reproducible example in your question - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#Define web driver as a Chrome driver and navigate
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

url = 'https://superbet.ro/cautare?query=Steaua'
driver.get(url)

# Click on accept cookies
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()

# Save all the events in a list
events = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "event-row-container")))

# Then with that list I do whatever I want, in this example only showing the text
for event in events:
    print(event.text)
```

As you can see I am using `presence_of_element_located` or `presence_of_all_elements_located` which is the best library.

I am not sure, but I would say `find_elements` will be deprecated

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution, using your code works as intended. I will look into the documentation of this library, had no idea there's another library that works better. However, for the sake of it, do you know why my code wasn't working?

Comment: your code probably wasn't working because you weren't waiting for the page to load completely. Since you did not share your code with us, we can't know the answer to this question for sure.